# I tried recreating a website on oswd for practice but the screen doesn't show anything other than the background

Tags: html, css

This is the code I wrote and I don't know what I did wrong, I'm trying to recreate this interface but all the content just disappears, the only thing that shows is a white rectangle on the top of the page...

This makes no sense to me and I don't know how to address it

[website taken from oswd.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KvUR.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <title>Bookish recreated by LuckyP</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=viewport-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Luca Santarelli">
        <meta name="description" content="Come to see the first practice website by LuckyP,
        commonly called Lucio, depending on the platform you watch him on">
        <meta name="robots" content="index">
        <meta name="keywords" content="bookish, real web development project">
        <style>
            *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    font-family:"trebuchet ms", helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(images/bg.gif);
}
#wrap{
    background-color:white;
    padding:15px;
    margin:auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.orange-text{
    color:#D97900;
}
.bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
header{
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(images/headbg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width:770px;
}
h1{
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    bottom:15px;
}
header ul{
    position:absolute;
    right:30px;
    bottom:15px;
}
header ul li{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-right:#D97900;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
}
header ul li:hover{
    background-color:#D97900;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <header>
                <h1><span class="orange-text">my</span><span class="bold">website</span>name</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">recent articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the output:

Answer (score 0):

Remove "bottom:15px;" from H1 and "header ul".